# The name for an anticipatory counter-argument?

Tags: logic, terminology

There's the argument *ad absurdum* along with several other kind of reasoning.

What is the name for a forestalling counter-argument - an argument put forward pre-emptively in anticipation of an argument expected in reply ?

Comment: Hello - I have reworded your question in a way I hope conveys its meaning more clearly. If you don't feel I've got it right, just re-edit. All the best - Geoffrey

Comment: They are called pre-emptive arguments or spikes, see [The Harms of Pre-emptive Argumentation by Alessandro](https://www.vbriefly.com/2014/10/30/spikes/). But there is no analogy to argument by contradiction. The latter indicates a type of logical structure, spiking is not a "kind of reasoning", it is just a rhetorical strategy that has nothing to do with argument's substance, quality or validity.

Comment: Please, turn this into an answer. I am interested in info about this kind of arguments. Thank you for your answer!